# compilation error when porting AudioKit iOS app to Catalyst macOS app

Tags: audiokit, xcframework

I have an iOS app that has been working fine with AudioKit's iOS build.  I wanted to try porting to macOS w Catalyst by dropping in AudioKit.xcframework.  Here is what I did

1. compile AudioKit-4.9.5 from source to generate AudioKit.xcframework (I had previously been using a locally compiled AudioKit iOS framework from the same source release with no issues on the non-Catalyst version)
2. in the "General" tab,

   - checked Mac as a deployment target
   - removed the old AudioKit iOS framework
   - added AudioKit.xcframework
3. in "Build Settings" tab,

   - change "Framework Search Paths" from the parent directory of the AudioKit iOS framework to the parent directory of AudioKit.xcframework
4. in the "Build Phases" tab,

   - AudioKit.xcframework appears in "Link Binary with Libraries"
   - AudioKit.xcframework appears in "Embed Frameworks"

I receive the following errors,

[image: AudioKit.xcframework compilation errors]

Currently using Xcode 11.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here since this issue seems to be an artifact of the AudioKit module containing a AudioKit class.  Renaming AudioKit class to something else fixes the issue although I'd discourage folks from doing this and instead waiting for a future AudioKit release that does this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I ended up editing the `x86_64-apple-ios-macabi.swiftinterface` file and correct the interface by hand.

I only had to prefix `AudioKit.` in from of the identifier unresolved. It looks more like a bug with the XCFramework build configuration / the swiftinterface generator.

I also run into a crash at runtime when using `AKSampler()`. For some reason the compiler do not understand that `.init()` do not exist and that it should use the `AKSampler(masterVolume: 1.0, pitchBend: 0.0, ... filterEnvelopeVelocityScaling: 0.0)` prototype. Calling by hand with the default values fix it.

Edit: You do not need to explicitly call the long initializer, you simply have to remove the line:

```
  @objc override dynamic public init()
```

from the `@objc open class AKSampler : AKPolyphonicNode, AKComponent {` section.

---

To summarize:
Edit the `x86_64-apple-ios-macabi.swiftinterface` in the XCFramework/
`AudioKit.output` and `AudioKit.midi.client` in place of the unresolved identifier.

If you use AKSampler, remove the line:

```
  @objc override dynamic public init()
```

from the `@objc open class AKSampler : AKPolyphonicNode, AKComponent {` section.